# Using Reflection.Emit to implement generic interface

Tags: c#, generics, reflection.emit

I'm using [Reflection.Emit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.aspx) to define a new type, and I'd like the type to implement [`IComparable(T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd.aspx), where `T` would be the newly defined type.

```
class DefinedType : IComparable<DefinedType>
{
//...
}
```

It seems to me like I have a chicken-and-egg problem.

As a fallback, I can always just implement `IComparable`, but if possible I'd like the generic interface; I just can't see how I can do it using Emit, because the type doesn't exist before I define it.

Comment: Wish I had time to play with this.. but I am looking forward to someone else answering!

Comment: I see a method [`addInterfaceImplementation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder.addinterfaceimplementation(v=vs.110).aspx) that you can call on your [`TypeBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) after you've constructed a new type. Wouldn't you be able to add the `Comparable<YourType>` afterwards to your type using that method?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I don't think that's allowed. I'm pretty sure you can only call `CreateType` once.

Comment: @anthony-arnold: [This](http://dotnetfiddle.net/UL2PV5) is how far I got right now with the code of Jared, which results in [this compiled code](http://i.imgur.com/Tw1ql96.png). We're almost there except the class itself also holds a generic parameter now. I haven't found a way yet to work around the adding of the generic parameter to the class since it is needed to create the generic type for the interface. I'll keep looking, but you might be helped with this intermediate result.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I think we're overthinking it. I'm currently working out a solution where I just have `DefinedTypeBase` and `class DefinedType : DefinedTypeBase, IComparable<DefinedTypeBase>`.

Comment: @anthony-arnold: that sounds possible as well but will require a different signature though.. I'm working in the direction of creating a type that is just meant as trash and not be used. That way I can define the generic parameter on there without soiling the actual type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
var tb = mb.DefineType("Test", TypeAttributes.Public);
var iface = typeof(IComparable<>).MakeGenericType(tb);
tb.AddInterfaceImplementation(iface);

var meb = tb.DefineMethod("CompareTo", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Virtual, typeof(int), new [] { tb } );
var il = meb.GetILGenerator();
il.ThrowException(typeof(Exception));

var type = tb.CreateType();
```

Fortunately, TypeBuilder inherits from Type, so you can use it in `MakeGenericType`.

As a verification, this works:

```
var o1 = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
var o2 = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

typeof(IComparable<>).MakeGenericType(o1.GetType()).GetMethod("CompareTo").Invoke(o1, new [] { o2 }).Dump();
```

You don't have to bind the generated method to the interface in any way, it's enough that their signature is the same. Doing explicit interface implementation might be a bit more tricky, but you shouldn't need that.

Comment: Oh, I see svick's answer already suggests this. Well, here's a full working sample, so feel free to accept svick's answer or mine as you wish :)

Answer (score 2):

When calling `MakeGenericType()` to turn `IComparable<>` into `IComparable<DefinedType>`, you can just pass it your `TypeBuilder`. The code could look something like:

```
var boundComparerType = typeof(IComparable<>).MakeGenericType(typeBuilder);
typeBuilder.AddInterfaceImplementation(boundComparerType);
```