How to use a generic type with a runtime-defined type parameter in Reflection.Emit
Running this under .NET 8.
IJoinable<T1, T2> already exists in the codebase as a generic interface.  It declares one method, T2 Join(T1 value).  The types being used for the type parameters (lType, rType,  joinedType) are TypeBuilder variables that have been dynamically generated at runtime.
    var joinType = typeof(IJoinable<,>).MakeGenericType(rType, joinedType);
    lType.AddInterfaceImplementation(joinType);
    var joinMethod = lType.DefineMethod("Join", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Virtual, joinedType, [rType]);
    var gen = joinMethod.GetILGenerator();
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, ctor);
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
    lType.DefineMethodOverride(joinMethod, joinType.GetMethod("Join")!);

When I call joinType.GetMethod() on that last line, it throws NotSupportedException, because somehow it ended up inside of System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilderInstantiation.GetMethodImpl(), whose entire method body is to throw NotSupportedException.
If that doesn't work, what's the right way to do this?

Because joinType doesn't extend a class with an existing implementation of that method? Why are you generating this method using IL? Are you building this just to call a constructor with known arguments? Can you simply use a static abstract factory method? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-11.0/static-abstracts-in-interfaces

@JeremyLakeman Of course joinType isn't extending any classes; it's an interface.  As for why I'm generating this method using IL, it's because I'm generating all of the types seen here (except for the IJoinable interface) using IL.  The simple answer is, "this is a script compiler."  (The complicated version gets pretty complicated pretty quickly.)

So either https://stackoverflow.com/a/21044626/4139809 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/1822169/4139809 ?

Are you sure the exception is thrown by joinType.GetMethod?

@JeremyLakeman Wow.  Not calling DefineMethodOverride seems to work.  Why, then, does the documentation make it look like it's needed?

@shingo Quite sure.  I'm in the debugger looking at it.

Dunno, but I think if the method is .Public | .Virtual the interface implementation is discovered implicitly. But something about your method involving generic type parameters fails when you call DefineMethodOverride... no idea.

@JeremyLakeman The error wasn't the call to DefineMethodOverride, it was the call to GetMethod.  Apparently specializing a generic type with a TypeBuilder for a type argument gives you a TypeBuilderInstantiation as the result, which is useless because basically all of its methods throw NotSupportedException.

To perform operations involving Reflection.Emit and generics, there are three somewhat hidden, yet in plain sight, static methods on TypeBuilder:

TypeBuilder.GetMethod
TypeBuilder.GetConstructor
TypeBuilder.GetField

These methods operate on TypeBuilderInstantiation objects. Therefore, the call that fails using the classic GetMethod method needs to be replaced with one like this:
var genericMethod = TypeBuilder.GetMethod(joinType, typeof(IJoinable<,>).GetMethod("Join"));
Actually, I think the documentation for these methods is quite good (TypeBuilder.GetMethod). However, they deviate from the pattern established by other parts of the Reflection.Emit API, making them somewhat difficult to find.

Thanks!  I knew something that did this had to exist somewhere; I just didn't know where to look.  You're a lifesaver!
